# How to enable -allowProvisioningUpdates in VSTS xcode task?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops

I am creating an iOS app from VSTS using Xcode task with automatic signing and getting this error:

No profiles for 'X' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'X'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

How an I enable that option in VSTS Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, you can add the -allowProvisioningUpdates in the arguments option in the Xcode Task. see the attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: @starian: Okay, Thanks.